# How can i Set value for input text using flask?

Tags: python, flask

I use python 2.7 , and i want to set value for input textfield in HTML when i click some button , using flask . 
How to do this ?

```
def submit_textarea():
    text = request.form.get("text")
    outfile = codecs.open('output.txt', 'w', 'utf-8')
    outfile.write(text)

    return render_template("index.html")
```

this function get the text and sends it to text file i want to set some text for other input textfield .

Answer (score -1):

I'm not entirely sure if I understand your question, but I think this is what you're trying to do...

`index.html`

```
<form action="/get-text" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first_name">
    <input type="submit" value="Go">
</form>
```

As you can see, the name of the text field is `first_name`.

`app.py`

```
@app.route('/get-text', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def foo():
    bar = request.form['first_name']
```

This example will store whatever is typed into the text input when you hit GO in the variable `bar`.

Comment: this is done in text area , but i want to set in the textfield  other text , i mean i want to made if statements , e.g ,  when i click the button 
if (var = "hi ") : 
set "yees" in the text field